# Lettrine with hebrew bidi problem

Tags: hebrew, bidi, lettrine

After update TeXLive on 18.10.2022 (all packets) I get problem with `xelatex` compilng this combination:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguages{hebrew}% <- problem with this string 
\begin{document}
Test
\lettrine{T}{est}
\end{document}
```

There is no problem with other language, like greek, russian etc, but only with **hebrew**.
`LuaLatex` compile it without problem.

All worked fine several month ago (at June this year).

Comment: bidi patches lettrine but hasn't updated these patches to the current lettrine version. See https://github.com/kvafa/bidi/issues/13. Falling back to an older lettrine version doesn't work either, so imho you are out of luck with xelatex.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in last (08.11.22) TexLive update.